# Solving binomial coefficient inequality

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients

I have the following inequality, 
$$\binom{\binom{n}{k}}{a}\binom{\binom{n}{k-l}}{b}<\binom{\binom{n}{k}}{a+b}\tag 1$$
I was wondering how one solves this exact / approximately for l?

Comment: Just checking - we assume that all variables are known except $l$, and we want to find the values of $l$ for which the inequality is true, right?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins yes that is true.

Comment: does my answer work for you?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins unfortunately not, as I will need an analytical form.

Comment: what makes you think that it is at all possible? Searching for zeros of high-dimensional polynomials is a notoriously hard problem which is unsolvable analytically for dimensions 5 and higher, and you can't solve inequalities if you can't solve for zeros. I can refer you to a few publications if you wish. Unless there is some significant symmetry in the above expression that I missed, it is very unlikely that it is solvable analytically

Comment: Why did you delete your last question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2907352/solving-an-equation-involving-logab. It was an interesting problem I was working on. Would you undelete it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you substitute all combination expressions inside and open all the brackets, you will end up with a fraction $\frac{P(l)}{Q(l)} < 0$, where $P(l)$ and $Q(l)$ are polynomials. You can then attempt to [factorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials) each polynomial into linear multipliers and apply the [standard high-school polynomial inequality solution method](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/ineqpoly.htm) to determine for which intervals of the real line is the LHS of the equation positive and for which negative, and then determine which integer values of $l$ fit into the positive intervals.

However, if you do that, you will get into a giant mess, because factoring a polynomial containing products of products of factorials will give you thousands of zeros on your real line. Since $l$ is integer, why not just write a computer program checking if the inequality holds for each value of $l$ from $0$ to $k$?